# Facebook get wall by time limit

Tags: facebook, api, datetime, sdk, facebook-fql

I am getting wall posts by facebook sdk

$get = $facebook->api('/me/posts', 'GET' );
or
$get = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'GET' );

I need to save them into my own DB, and after new request, I need get posts, that I have not saved yet. But I could not find any parameters to add to get info for example last 7 days, or after post by timestamp smth.

I saw that there is FQL which has time field, but it was only in Statuses table, I need all of them, likes, shares, statuses, comments etc.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/, sub-section “Paging”

Answer (score 0):

You can add `since=[time]` and/or `until=[time]` as query strings to get a specific slice of time.

For instance, to get 7 days of posts beginning on October 1, 2012, try this:

```
'/me/feed?since=2012-10-01&until=2012-10-08'
```

Your time string can be either an ISO-8601 date string or a UNIX timestamp.